# Firewall security in AWS

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, firewall

Currently AWS provides NAT, network ACLs and security groups for their virtual private cloud.

Are these security features sufficient for a multi-tier architecture deployment (ie web, application and db servers), assuming all web, application and database servers are present in the VPC?

What other firewall features are needed for a such multi-tier architecture deployment?

Thanks!

Comment: yes,  and it works well.  You can set firewall rulesets by groups of machines.

Answer (score 0):

AWS security groups are analogous to firewall rules. To set up multi-tier architectures, have your tiers be members of specific security groups, and have each security group permit access on only the required ports / protocols to the other groups in order to create your tier communication channels.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

But how about things like logging of all connections that were permitted/denied? Or things like inspect ftp where secondary connections are created and should be dynamically be allowed through the security groups?

Are there equivalent AWS features for it?

Comment: I'm not sure about logging of permitted / denied connections. You could always use a commercial software firewall if you'd like that feature but must use AWS. For passive FTP, your FTP server (e.g. FileZilla Server) should be able to allow you to specify a port range in which the dynamic connections will open ports (the server sends the port to the client in the initial handshake). You can then put the same port ranges in AWS security groups in order to permit this. AFAIK, you can also specify that one group can accept all connections provided they originate from another group.